# Error: Call to undefined function in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have function:

```
private function generate_id($gencounter){
    $maxint = PHP_INT_MAX;
    $temp=$this->crypto_rand_secure(1, $maxint);
    if($gencounter<$maxint){
        if($this->check_id($temp)){
            $gencounter=0;
            $id=$temp;
            return $id;
        }
        else {
            $gencounter=$gencounter+1;
            generate_id($gencounter);
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and i'm calling it like this:

```
$user=array(
        'ID'=>$this->generate_id(0),
        [ rest of array ]
);
```

and i'm recieveing " Error: Call to undefined function generate_id()".
When I was building site on local server in XAMPP it worked fine but on the live server it gives me this error.

Comment: Where have you defined that function & from you are calling it?

Comment: Where are you calling your function from? Note that it is a private function

Comment: Can you show the classes? I suspect this is an access modifier problem.

Comment: everything is in same controller (inside class PartnersController extends AppController {...} )

Comment: your `if ($gencounter<PHP_INT_MAX)` test is rather pointless - a recursive function that called itself that many times would trigger an infinite recursion error. Why are you writing a function like that recursively anyway? Just use a loop. It also [may not work](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/abdef27a4c8cf814ee32) depending on what version of php/the environment.

Answer (score 4):

`$this` always refers to the object, in which a method exists, itself.
Take a look at your else block. There you call the method wrong.

Try this:

```
private function generate_id($gencounter){
    $maxint = PHP_INT_MAX;
    $temp=$this->crypto_rand_secure(1, $maxint);
    if($gencounter<$maxint){
        if($this->check_id($temp)){
            $gencounter=0;
            $id=$temp;
            return $id;
        }
        else {
            $gencounter=$gencounter+1;
            $this->generate_id($gencounter);
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer but now i'm curious why it works in XAMPP?